# Is there anyway to make a jQuery UI Datepicker unclickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

Is there anyway to make a [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) unclickable, so that it's essentially just displaying a date? I tried

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({ 
    disabled: true,
    altField: '#note_date',
    maxDate: 0
});
```

but it didn't work. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ay6Nv/

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [new Date(this.value).getDate() == date.getDate()];
    }
});​
```

Comment: You can still change month with this implementation.

If you change the last line to 


    return [new Date(this.value) == date];

you can't change date but the today td is missing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the readonly attribute at the input like this :

```
<input type='text' value='24/01/2019' readonly="readonly" />
```